# Devise + STI + Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization, sti

I have the following situation:

My app has several types of users: `Owner`, `Team Member`, `Collaborator`, `Client`<del>, and `Guest`</del>. <sup>(the Guest type isn't relevant for this question)</sup>

These are the connections between the different models:

- `Owner` **belongs_to** `Account`
- `Account` **has_many** `Team Members`
- `Account` **has_many** `Projects`
- `Projects` **habtm** *(or hmt)* `Collaborators`
- `Project` **habtm** *(or mht)* `Clients`

There are four key functions I need for my authentication & authorization:

- Be able to upgrade a Collaborator to a Team Member (this means removing all habtm's to Projects, and add a belongs_to to Account
- Be able to have different Devise strategies for different users (Owners have registerable, clients do not)
- Have different login pages which only accept a subset of users (separate login for owner/team members/collaborators and clients)
- Be able to call the different subset of users using Account.owner, Account.team_members, Project.collaborators, and Project.clients

I have gone over several solutions in my head, but I am unsure which would work best in my situation.

- At first I thought about using Devise for both the authorization and authentication, but I figured I'd better use something like CanCan for the authorization part.
- I also considered using one table for each user type, but that would make it harder to change roles after initial creation
- I am now dubbing on using STI fo have TeamMember < User, Client < User, etc. But since Clients and Collaborators belong to Projects and Owners and Team Members belong to an Account, I am not sure that will work easily with STI, and I also haven't really found any good examples on Devise with STI.

Any ideas how to solve this situation?